# how to show interstitial every click button 3 times?

Tags: java, android

how to show interstitial every click button 3 times ?

```
public void countIN (View view) {
counter++;
showValue.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
if (counter == 3) {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
}else {

}}
```

i use my code , and I trying to show interstitial ads in my app, but my interstitial just show 1 times.
i want to show my interstitial every click 3times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either by resetting the counter

```
if (counter == 3) {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
    counter = 0
}
```

or using modulo

```
if (counter % 3 == 0) {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @DevonJoe I highly doubt that. Add logging statement to see when the if body is reached. Probably `mInterstitialAd` is the problem.